# Multiple the numbers of a specific column with a number in libre office

Tags: libreoffice-calc

How can I multiple the numbers of column A with the number eg 5? I use LibreOffice. Thank you

Answer (score 9, accepted):

1. Enter the factor (multiplicant) `5` in an empy cell and copy it (<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>);
2. Select the column with the values to multiply;
3. Select Menu `Edit` -> `Paste special...` (or hit <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>);
4. Under `Operations`, select `Multiply` - leave everything else as default; hit <kbd>OK</kbd>:

   [image]

That's it - LO Calc will multiply the selected cell values with the value copied in step 1.

Comment: That was incredible! Thank you!